# Does the latest Scofield Reference Bible delete or substantially alter any of the original notes?

Tags: bible, kjv, fundamentalism

There's some controversy about differences between the original Scofield reference bible and the latest editions, which were edited by a committee after Dr Scofield's death. I'm wondering whether any of Scofield's original notes have been modified or deleted, and if so which ones and to what extent? Or is the new edition just an "amplification" of the original which adds more notes and maps and etc, but leaves the original text as it was?

Answer (score 3):

In 1967, Oxford University Press published a revision of the Scofield Bible with a slightly modernized KJV text, and a muting of some of the tenets of Scofield's theology. The editors' introduction states that these revisions follow the same doctrine:

[image]

However, The Story of the King James Version, 1611-2011 (Oxford University Press, 2010) comes to the opposite conlusion regarding the alterations:

> "The continuing popularity of the 1917 notes may reflect the
>   preference of the purchasers for the original and full-strength
>   Scofield." Mangum & Sweetnam suggest the popularity of the 1917
>   edition may also reflect a strong commitment to the KJV translation.
>   **Scofield was accused of promoting "two ways of salvation" with a
>   dispensation of works before the death and resurrection of Christ and
>   a dispensation of grace afterwards. In the revision of 1967,
>   Scofield's note on John 1:17 "was rewritten, and now seemed to say the
>   opposite of Scofield's original**." Gordon Campbell, Bible: The Story of
>   the King James Version, 1611-2011 (Oxford University Press, 2010),
>   246-47.

Recent editions of the KJV Scofield Study Bible have **moved the textual changes made in 1967 to the margin**.